# Why have both paper-fab and paper-icon-button components?

Tags: polymer, material-design

Polymer has a `paper-icon-button`:
https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-icon-button

Polymer also has a `paper-fab`:
https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-fab/elements/paper-fab

I understand the design difference; that the [material design spec](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button) recommends [using these differently](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#buttons-button-types) (e.g. "Only one floating action button is recommended per screen"), but is there really any difference as far as the components go? Or is a `paper-fab` just a `paper-icon-button` with a pink background, a border radius, and a box shadow (three lines of css?). Basically, I don't understand why I should bother importing both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you commented, it is because of its behavior following Material Design spec. `<paper-fab>` is intended to represent the primary action of the app while `<paper-icon-button>` provide additional functionality.

Let's use Twitter mobile app as an example. In Android, it has a "paper fab" to post new tweets, and we can all agree that the main purpose of Twitter app is to post tweets so it makes sense to place a floating button for that action, while it has additional buttons represented as icons to add functionality, for example the *find contacts* button that you can find next to the search bar.

**Note:** Take into account the date this answer was posted as Twitter UI could have been changed since then. If example description is not clear, please comment it and I will try to post a screenshot.

Concerning the implementation in Polymer of these components, both uses `<iron-icon>` and we could consider the code "pretty close", you can check them here: [`<paper-icon-button>`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-icon-button/blob/master/paper-icon-button.html) and [`<paper-fab>`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-fab/blob/master/paper-fab.html)

So, in conclusion, despite thinking they are pretty much the same, it is good to use them as different components as they represent different things.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, but I don't understand why I should import both dependencies into my app. It seems like a total waste to do so when they only differ in style and usage, not really in functionality.

Comment: @TeddyWard A couple of reasons could be because of reusability and maintainability. If you want to include a floating button without paper-fab button, you should need to "reinvent the wheel" and maybe repeat the same styles in several pages where you include a floating button (and your code could smell specially when you want to change something). That's up to you to wrap a paper-icon-button with divs and styles or whatever to set a floating action without paper-fab, but someone could think that you are not taking advantage of all benefits web components technologies provide.

Comment: And if you think this is a total waste because of the two `<iron-icon>` imports in both components, Polymer is smart enough to import `<iron-icon>` only once. [link](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/4775)

Comment: I think having a turning the paper-fab component into essentially a single css class in a shared-styles file like

`.paper-fab {
  background-color: whatever;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: something;
}`

would be just as good in this case, but your answer makes sense